# Can I authenticate with OAuth in a Javascript app without saving a token on the client side with rauth?

Tags: django, angularjs, authentication, oauth, rauth

I want to be able to authenticate users of an angular.js application using oauth, but I do not want to store any tokens on the frontend because I have seen that it can be fairly complicated to do so securely. Is there a way to pass some sort of credentials of a user to my django web application, where is can authenticate the user with some oauth provider and save that information in a session? To make it simple, here is the process I want

1. User is logged into some oauth provider, i.e. stackexchange
2. They click a "login with stackexchange" button on the front end angular app
3. Their login credentials are sent over to the django application through a restful api
4. The django app which receives these credentials attempts to get a token using rauth
5. If the server receives a token, the user is logged in and their information is saved in a session, otherwise they are given an error

Is this sort of process supported by OAuth2 providers?

Answer (score 2):

Step 3 is incorrect: that authentication process is handled entirely off-site, on the OAuth provider's infrastructure, e.g. StackExchange.

This kind of flow is certainly possible. I would check out the [Facebook example](https://github.com/litl/rauth/tree/master/examples/facebook), which uses Flask, but provides a similar framework for how you might go about this in Django.